# Override JPA only Table Generator of Entity with orm.xml (Hibernate)

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have a JPA entity as follows:

```
public class Host {
    @Id
    @TableGenerator(name = "Host.id", schema = "Schema", table = "SEQUENCE", pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME", valueColumnName = "SEQ_COUNT", pkColumnValue = "Host.id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "Host.id", strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    protected Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(length = 64, nullable = false)
    protected String name;

    @Size(max = 64)
    @Column(length = 64)
    protected String hardwareType;

    @Size(max = 65535)
    @Column(length = 65535)
    protected String resourceDescription;
}
```

How can I override the Table Generator (without using the Hibernate specific `@GenericGenerator` annotation)?

Currently, I have a solution that defines a `<hibernate-mapping>` for the entity in a `orm.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.x.y.datamodel.config.equipment.Host" schema="Schema">
        <id name="id" column="id">
            <generator class="com.x.y.customtablegenerator.CustomTableGenerator"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name" column="name"></property>
        <property name="hardwareType" column="hardwareType"></property>
        ...
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

However, this requires me to add a `<property>` for every property defined in the Entity.

**Is there a way to override *only* the Generator without having to specify all the properties of the entity twice?**

Comment: `<table-generator>` is amply defined for `orm.xml`. http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_2/jpa/metadata_xml.html#table-generator

Comment: @BillyFrost I have tried that, but as far as I know the `name=` attribute does not allow you to specify a class? I need to override the built-in generators by specifying my own, i.e., `com.x.y.customtablegenerator.CustomTableGenerator`.

Comment: No idea for your provider since I don't use that one. The one I use allows the "strategy" of `generated-value` to be specified when using something other than the JPA supported generators. http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_2/jpa/mapping.html#valuegen_uuid  Blame all of that on the people who "designed" the JPA API for not allowing JPA providers to have a standard way of defining their own generators. Perhaps you should look at the docs for your JPA provider since this is totally specific to them

Comment: @BillyFrost The provider I use is Hibernate. Hibernate allows you to specify the generator by using their `@GenericGenerator` annotation. However, due to our data model (JPA entities) being used by another provider (EclipseLink) as well as JDBC accessors, I am not allowed to add any JPA provider specific annotations on the entities themselves. 
The `strategy` in the documentation refers to one of the built-in strategies, unfortunately.